# Finding topic of a post using ORM relationship

Tags: kohana, kohana-3.3

I have a table which stores posts created by user on a particular topic.each of these posts belong to one and only one topic. there is a column in the posts table which stores the id of the topic.  I would like to display all title of the posts in a page  categorized under topic name

example:

### Animals

Post 1

Post 2

Post 3

### Plants&Trees

Post 1

Post 2

Post 3

My  'posts' table is in following format
id
posttitle
posttext
topic_id

My 'topics' table is in following format
id
topicname

What relationship have to define so that i can access the topicname and id in the following name.

```
foreach($posts as $post)
echo $post->topics->topicname
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To say it in words, each topic **has many** posts and each post **belongs to** a topic - that is exactly what relationships you need.

When you have defined them, as described in the [documentation](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/orm/relationships), you can do something like this:

```
$topics = ORM::factory("topic")->find_all();
foreach ($topics as $topic) {
    // $topic->topicname
    foreach ($topic->posts as $post) {
        // $post->posttitle
    }
}
```